# Rails association via two routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

Two questions here related to the same problem.
One is modelled with a polymorphic association, the other with a standard association.

I have a model which can have two paths to the same item.

```
Client
has_many :opportunities
has_many :notes, as: :notable
has_many :emails

Opportunity
has_many :notes, as: :notable
has_many :emails

Note
attr accessible :notable_id, :notable_type
belongs_to :notable

Email
attr_accessible :client_id, :opportunity_id
belongs_to :client
belongs_to :opportunity
```

As such
Client can

```
has_many :notes, through: :opportunity
has_many :emails, through: :opportunity
```

I can't work out how to model the situation where I want all the notes, or all the emails related to a client, regardless of whether they're 'one step removed'.

i.e. I want to do something like

```
@client.all_emails
```

and return all emails whether they are directly connected to the client or one of their associated opportunities
and

```
@client.all_notes
```

and return all notes likewise

I should note that in both cases, the client can often have both notes and emails without a relevant opportunity interceding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create method for this, this can not be done using assoications

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base

  def all_emails
    Email.joins("INNER JOIN client ON clients.id = emails.client_id AND clients.id = ? INNER JOIN opportunity ON opportunities.id = emails.opportunity_id AND opportunities.id IN (?)", id, opportunity_ids)
  end

  # same way for notes
emd
```